# tty a must to run sudo in fabric. How to overcome this?

Tags: mono, fastcgi, fabric

I uses fabric to run a fastcgi_mono service via the command:

```
sudo('/etc/init.d/fastcgi_mono restart', pty=False)
```

But when I execute it, it gives me this error:

```
[52.192.204.174] run: sudo /etc/init.d/fastcgi_mono restart
[52.192.204.174] out: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
[52.192.204.174] out: 


Warning: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing 'sudo /etc/init.d/fastcgi_mono restart'!
```

how do I solve this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found the answer. For Amazon instances, you need to disable requiretty

```
comment('/etc/sudoers', 'Defaults    requiretty', use_sudo=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i solve this is, I dont know if there is a better way but it makes sense in my head: I have two users set up in my fabfile.py, `ubuntu` (which has sudo privileges) and `www-data` (which does not have any real rights, only can add/delete directories in its "space" (/server/*)). I always establish connections using `ubuntu` that way i can use `sudo()` when ever i need to. When ever i need to do something at the application level, what i call `def deploy()` i connect using the application user, so i do something like:

```
@settings(user='www-data')
def deploy():
    run('whoami')  # will say www-data
```

or if i need to do some kind of `sudo()` inside my `deploy()` i'll do:

```
def deploy():
    sudo('whoami')  # will say ubuntu/root
    with settings(user='www-data'):
         run('whoami')  # will say www-data
         ... more code here
```

so recap:

- Connect using a user that has sudo access
- Change the user to a higher level user if need be later

Comment: the OS is amazon linux. I use ec2-user

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ doesnt matter. On ec2 the root is `ubuntu`, just create another user that has no real permissions